# What makes a food plant good for a small aquaponics system?

Tags: aquaponics

I have a small aquafarm, and I have a couple of danios and a cory in it.  When I started out, I put some wheatgrass in it, and that grew like crazy.  I want to put some variety into it.  Does anyone have recommendations for edible plants?

Edit: I revised the title to get more informative answers on what attributes a plant should have to thrive.

Comment: You could try some lettuce :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any type of micro-green is generally very easy to grow, but I have seen people grow tomatoes, squash, peppers, etc. As long as you have the room and the light required otherwise, you shouldn't have a problem growing food in an aquaponic system that you wouldn't otherwise have.

Answer (score 3):

You can try lots of things but Swiss chard, lettuce, pickles / cucumbers, tomatoes, strawberries and chilis should all be relatively easy. Leafy vegetables should generally be easy but do experiment as in part the question of what crops work with your system will depend on the specifics of what you build and how it is positioned...